# Mongorestore 4.2 can work with AWS DocumentDB 4.0?

Tags: mongodb, amazon-web-services, mongodump, aws-documentdb

I'm trying to migrate my mongodb(4.2) to AWS DocumentDB(4.0). I meet the below problem when I try to restore the backup data by **mongorestore**:

```
$ time sudo mongorestore \
> --host="x.x.x.x:27017" \
> --ssl --sslCAFile ~/rds-combined-ca-bundle.pem \
> --username=user --password=passwd \
> --db db \
> --dir /mongodump \
> -vvvvv \
> --numInsertionWorkersPerCollection 128 \
>
2020-11-19T07:46:39.507+0000    using --dir flag instead of arguments
2020-11-19T07:46:39.507+0000    using write concern: &{majority false 0}


2020-11-19T07:47:09.508+0000    error connecting to host: could not connect to server: server selection error: server selection timeout
current topology: Type: Single
Servers:
Addr: shw-docdb-test-migration.cluster-caxwucwjitxo.ap-southeast-2.docdb.amazonaws.com:27017, Type: Unknown, State: Connected, Average RTT: 0, Last error: connection(shw-docdb-test-migration.cluster-caxwucwjitxo.ap-southeast-2.docdb.amazonaws.com:27017[-121]) connection is closed
```

Any ideas about this error?

Thank you,
Shawn

Answer (score 3):

Thinking I found a way to resolve this issue, I used docker to run this mongorestore 4.0, then the dump data can be restored to the docdb:

```
docker run --detach  \
--volume /home/ec2-user:/ec2-user \
--volume /mongodump:/dumpdir \
mongo:4.0.18-xenial


dockerid=`docker ps|grep -v IMAGE|awk '{print $1}'`

time sudo docker exec -it $dockerid \
mongorestore --host xxxx \
--ssl --sslCAFile /ec2-user/rds-combined-ca-bundle.pem \
--port 27017 \
--verbose \
-u xxx -p xxxx \
--db dbtest \
--dir /dumpdir/dbtest \
-vvvvv \
--numInsertionWorkersPerCollection 128 \
```

So basically, the data from MongoDB v4.2 can be restored into the DocumentDB v 4.0, the only thing that needs to do is to choose the mongorestore v4.0.

Hope this answer can help you.

Thank you,
Shawn

Answer (score 0):

it looks like the client that you are using for mongorestore is not able to connect to the DocumentDB cluster. The common reasons for that are 1/client is not in the same VPC as the DocumentDB cluster, 2/security group for the DocumentDB cluster does not enable inbound connections on the default port of 27017.

Please see connection issues for more troubleshooting options: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/documentdb/latest/developerguide/troubleshooting.connecting.html

Comment: I can log in to the docdb from same box, is that meaning the mongorestore 4.2 is not compatible to the docdb? `[ec2-user@ip-10-84-0-29 ~]$  mongo  --host xxx --ssl --sslCAFile ~/rds-combined-ca-bundle.pem --username xxx --password xxx
2020-11-19T23:19:23.252+0000 W  CONTROL  [main] Option: ssl is deprecated. Please use tls instead.
2020-11-19T23:19:23.252+0000 W  CONTROL  [main] Option: sslCAFile is deprecated. Please use tlsCAFile instead.
MongoDB shell version v4.2.1
.....
.....
rs0:PRIMARY> show dbs
testdb  0.000GB
tbl-dms-ctl  0.000GB`

Comment: With mongorestore 4.2 you need to use tls instead of ssl in the connection string. So tlsCAFile and tls instead of sslCAFile and ssl.

Answer (score 0):

## Restore Mongo dump to a DocumentDB using mongorestore 4.2 version fails

```
sudo docker run --rm -it -v /tmp:/app mongo:4.2 bash
mongorestore --tls --host documentdb.cluster-clodkmgd3rhk.ap-southeast-1.docdb.amazonaws.com:27017 --tlsCAFile rds-combined-ca-bundle.pem --username dbadmin --password <PASSWORD>
...
2022-10-21T14:37:58.510+0000    error connecting to host: could not connect to server: server selection error: server selection timeout, current topology: { Type: Single, Servers: [{ Addr: documentdb.cluster-clodkmgd3rhk.ap-southeast-1.docdb.amazonaws.com:27017, Type: Unknown, State: Connected, Average RTT: 0, Last error: connection() : x509: certificate signed by unknown authority }, ] }
```

## Restore Mongo dump to a DocumentDB using mongorestore 4.0 version fails

```
sudo docker run --rm -it -v /tmp:/app mongo:4.0 bash
mongorestore --tls --host documentdb.cluster-clodkmgd3rhk.ap-southeast-1.docdb.amazonaws.com:27017 --tlsCAFile rds-combined-ca-bundle.pem --username dbadmin --password <PASSWORD>
...
restoring indexes for collection database.collection from metadata
Failed: database.collection: error creating indexes for database.collection: createIndex error: Field '' is currently not supported
```

## Restore Mongo dump to a DocumentDB using latest mongorestore version fails

```
mongorestore --ssl --host documentdb.cluster-clodkmgd3rhk.ap-southeast-1.docdb.amazonaws.com:27017 --sslCAFile rds-combined-ca-bundle.pem --username dbadmin --password <PASSWORD>
finished restoring database.collection (63673 documents, 0 failures)
Failed: database.collection: error creating indexes for database.collection: createIndex error: Index type not supported : text
63673 document(s) restored successfully. 0 document(s) failed to restore.
```

Can’t restore dump from MongoDB Atlas Cloud 4.2 to AWS DocumentDB 4.0.

I tried to restore in a different ways but no luck.

Tried to restore MongoDB Atlas Cloud 4.2 to a MongoDB 4.4.6-8 on EC2 and configure sync using Amazon DMS.

## Restore Mongo dump to a current production MongoDB Replica Set on EC2 success

```
mongorestore -u admin -p <PASSWORD> -d test --authenticationDatabase=admin ./dump/database
...
2022-10-21T15:34:45.650+0000    1318333 document(s) restored successfully. 0 document(s) failed to restore.
```

After that I successfully created Database migration task from current production MongoDB Replica Set on EC2 to a AWS DocumentDB